# My if-else statement isn't working with the list I used

Tags: python

So I entered 3 as my eye color (green) and it displays "You are a optimistic person" instead of "you are a curious person". Why is this? Isn't it supposed to display the else?

```
eyeList = ["blue", "brown","green","hazel","grey","none"]

print(eyeList)

eyecolor = int(input("Pick your eye color: "))

if eyecolor == 1 or 2:

  print("you are a  optimistic person")

else:
  print("you are a curious person")
```

Comment: The _equality_ operator is `==`. When you write `=` in your if condition, you're attempting to do _assignment_. (edit: fixed)

Comment: You are missing the colons, `:` at the end of your `if`/`elif` lines.

Comment: ok, no error, but nothing shows up when I type in a trait for "Pick a trait from the list: "

Comment: What are you entering as inputs? Is it "shy", "sociable" , "loud"? Or "0", "1", "2"?

Answer (score 1):

Python syntax:

```
if condition:
    Indented expressions
elif condition2:
    Other expressions
else:
    Further expressions
```

You are simply missing the *colons* (`:`) after each condition.

Furthermore, to check if something is equal to something else, you have to use `==`. A single `=` performs an assignment.

```
if variable == 42:
    variable = 7
```

Finally, you cannot compare integers to strings (`input()` function returns a string). In order to do it convert the string into an integer:

```
IntegerValue = int(stringFormat)
```

**Final tip**: your console gives you useful hints about what's wrong in the code. Listen to them.

Answer (score 1):

1. `personality` might be a `string`, use `int(input(...))` to get an `int`
2. you cannot compare `int` to `string`
3. the equality operator is `==`, not `=`
4. you need the colon `:` after every `if` or `elif` line

something like this might work:

```
myList = ["shy","sociable","loud"]
print(myList)
try :
    personality = int(input("Pick a trait from the list: "))
except ValueError :
    sys.exit("Invalid input: " + str(personality))

if personality == 0 :
  print("You are a person who doesn't doesn't like talking to other people")
elif personality == 1 :
  print("you talk to people, but aren't really loud")
elif personality == 2 :
  print("You love talking to people and you are very loud")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues:

a) Input is taken as string, you need to convert it in `int`

b) You put wrong syntax for checking, it should be two **equal signs** `==`

c) Skip the `:` at the end of the `if`

Fixed code:

```
myList = ["shy","sociable","loud"]
print(myList)
personality = int(input("Pick a trait from the list: "))

if personality == 0:
  print("You are a person who doesn't doesn't like talking to other people")
elif personality == 1:
  print("you talk to people, but aren't really loud")
elif personality == 2:
  print("You love talking to people and you are very loud")
```